# I am trying to do update on query side

Tags: cqrs, axon

What I am doing is that i am trying to get the aggregate from repository and then process that particular event and mark it as a new event...so that query  recognizes that it is a update event. 
But the problem is that I am not able to get that particular aggregate.

What I have done is here:

```
LockAwareAggregate<CustomerAggregate, EventSourcedAggregate<CustomerAggregate>> lockCustomerAggregate = 
    customerEventSourcingRepository.load(command.getId().toString());

EventSourcedAggregate<CustomerAggregate> eventSourcedCustomerAggregate = 
    lockCustomerAggregate.getWrappedAggregate();

CustomerAggregate customerAggregate = eventSourcedCustomerAggregate.getAggregateRoot();

customerAggregate.updateAddress(command.getAddress());
```

I used this code in 2.4.3 and it was returning a `CustomerAggregate` but right now it's returning a `LockAwareAggregate`.
Can you please suggest where I am getting wrong.

can you please also share whats message in
UnitOfWork work = DefaultUnitOfWork.startAndGet(message??);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your phrasing seems a bit off at the start, as it seems you intent to adjust your events in the event store which is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, what it sounds like is that you're retrieving events from your `EventStore` and you say you're updating them. I'd highly encourage **not** to do that.

You've `EventStore` should be append only. 
The events stored in it *have happened*, so that's *history*.
In real life you cannot adjust history, and that's how you should regard your events in the `EventStore` as well.

So, that's a warning.
Your code snippet luckily suggests you're just trying to call a function on your aggregate to perform a certain 'action'. Action is the keyword here, as it signals you're doing a 'command'. Thus, you could call that function just as easily through a `@CommandHandler` annotated field on your aggregate to adjust it. In doing that you will not have to load your aggregate manually.

Added, I can't really see which `Repository` implementation you're using to load your aggregate manually (I guess the `LockingRepository`), but I'd suggest to use the `Repository` interface rather than a specific implementation. 
That interface should return you an `Aggregate<T>`, were `T` is the `CustomerAggregate` in your example. That should give you the possibility to call the `updateAddresss()` function as desired.

**Probable answers**

1. In short, I think you're thus wiring the wrong `Repository` implementation in that snippet to load your aggregate.  Just using the `Repository` i.o. the `EventSourcingRepository` directly should do fine.
2. The `message` in the `UnitOfWork` your asking about can be any implementation of the `Message` interface. So that can be a Command, Event or a Query.

**Suggestion**
 1. I regularly suggest to not use the `Repository` directly though. Axon Framework can do the heavy lifting there, by letting you publish command on the `CommandBus`/`CommandGateway`. That, together with the `@CommandHandler` annotation on your command handling functions, makes it so that the framework will automatically load the right aggregate from the `Repository` and call that annotated function.

Comment: I'll Quote your answer from Added part...that's what exactly I am trying to do but I didn't get one thing, how you thought that I am trying to change EventStore, I am new to this but one thing is for sure I am not trying to change eventStore. And the repository you asked for is EventSourcingRepository<T>. Can you please suggest is there anything wrong in code that you got an overview that I am changing anything in evet store. Also please share what change I need to make.

Comment: can you please answer my comment.I really need to know if I am getting wrong anywhere.

Comment: I just edited the question, which may make it a bit more clearer what I'm explaining. It is quite basic though, so if this might end up to difficult, I definitely suggest watching some of the Webinars available on YouTube around starting an Axon Framework project.

And just as with your last questions I answered, if this solves your issue, could you please tick this question as the correct one? That makes it so other people are certain that the answer was answered sufficiently, so nicer bookkeeping in general.

Comment: I assume it solved your issue as you've marked it, great to hear that @AS!